# Excluir última linha - Java

Tags: java, string, csv, txt, stringbuilder

Estou realizando a leitura de um CSV usando BufferedReader lendo linha a linha convertendo o resultado em um .txt. No final do meu txt  está gerando uma quebra de linha depois do último item. 
Estou tentando encontrar uma forma de remover última quebra de linha a após a último item da lista.

Meu arquivo CSV tem 50 linhas.
Arquivo gerado txt tem 51 linhas.

```
public static void converter() throws Exception  {
    int EXPECTED = 15;      
    String fileName = txtCaminho.getText();
    String gerado = txtLocal.getText();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

    int x = 0;

    String aLine ;



   while ((aLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {

      StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(aLine, ",");
      if (token.countTokens() != EXPECTED) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, erro_messagem);
        throw new Exception("Illegal column count: " + token.countTokens());
      }
      x++;
      String form = token.nextToken();
      String ra = token.nextToken();
      String tipo = token.nextToken();   
      String q1 = token.nextToken();
      String q2 = token.nextToken();
      String q3 = token.nextToken();
      String q4 = token.nextToken();
      String q5 = token.nextToken();
      String q6 = token.nextToken();
      String q7 = token.nextToken();
      String q8 = token.nextToken();
      String q9 = token.nextToken();
      String q10 = token.nextToken();
      String q11 = token.nextToken();
      String q12 = token.nextToken();


      String newOrder = ra+";"+tipo+";" +q1 + q2 + q3 + q4 + q5 + q6 + q7 + q8 + q9 + q10 +q11+q12;

      String newBuffer = newOrder;

      System.out.print(newBuffer.replaceAll("\n", ""));

      gravar(gerado, newBuffer );
      System.out.println(x);
        }
      }
```

Função gravar ()

```
public static void gravar(String path, String texto)
  {
    try
    {     
      FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(path, true);
      BufferedWriter conexao = new BufferedWriter(fw);
      conexao.write(texto);
      conexao.newLine();

      conexao.close();

      txtCaminho.setText("");
      txtLocal.setText("");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que no seu método "gravar" você está forçando o "break line" logo após escrever o texto.

Uma das formas de evitar isso, ao invés de fazer o replace do \n, é evitar a quebra de linha.
O método **ready()** da classe BufferedReader vai te ajudar:

```
public void gravar(String path, String texto, boolean deveQuebrarLinha) {
  FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(path, true)
  BufferedWriter conexao = new BufferedWriter(fw);
  conexao.write(texto);

  if (deveQuebrarLinha)
    conexao.newLine();
}
```

E no seu método de leitura:

```
 public void converter() {
    String line;
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("seu-arquivo.txt"));
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {         
        gravar("path", line, reader.ready());
    }
 }
```

Documentação: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#ready()

Comment: Obrigado, ficou como esperado.